# Screen density same resolution

Tags: android, screen

I have two android devices with the same screen resolutions (800x480) and dimensions. 
The difference is that one screen is low density (120 dpi) and the other normal density (160 dpi).

I don't understand the reason by the same image of 200x200pixels is smaller in the screen with less density and if i write a rectangle of 200x200 pixels is the same on both screens.

Can anybody explain me the reason?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A 90 pixel image at ldpi becomes a 120 px a mdpi, a 180 at hdpi and a 240 ad xhdpi.

You can find more informations about it here (search "Screen pixel density") : [Dev Android Ressources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Another good link about Density : [Screen Support - Density](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)